# Displaying video in internal storage (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vue-component

I'm working on a Vue project that involves showing a video stored in a local directory

```
<video width="320" controls src="internal_path.mp4" type="video/mp4"
height="240" autoplay muted loop>
```

Is my code snippet for displaying the video but it doesn't work. I was confused on why it works for videos that are stored online, and how to fix it to show local videos as well.

The error message I get is vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Cannot find module

Answer (score 0):

Lok, most local storage directories on browsers limit to about ~10 MB or less and differs greatly across browsers.

See:
[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Even if it was a small video, lets say about 3MB, you would have to encode it then put it in the localstorage then decode it when you want to retrieve from the local storage.

MP4 file not encoded:

```
^@^@^@^Xftypmp42^@^@^@^@isommp42^@^A<86><98>moov^@^@^@lmvhd^@^@^@^@ÙÜR^YÙÜR^Y^@^@0^@^@7°O^@^A^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^>
0stco^@^@^@^@^@^@^B<88>^@^A<86>¸^@^CÝÞ^@^E^GA^@^E<8c>n^@^F%<96>^@^Fæ@^@^G<9c>^H^@^Hn¢^@ F2^@^L)ê^@^NÔ3^@^PI/^@^R^B<9a>^@^RLÖ^@^Rs^_^@^SRk^@^Sö<8e>^@^T<90>^H^@^U^V§^@^U´b^@^Y^F]^@^[>
E=^A^K^\^U^A^
```

This binary may cause problems.

There's ways to encode the video into base64 which can be encoded to and decoded from for easier handling with the raw data of the video file.

See:
[how to decode video from base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842768/how-to-decode-video-from-base64)

Also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: I think my language was unclear, by local I meant on my computer.

Comment: @K.Lok Ok, I understand what you mean now. Make sure the path to the that video file is *relative* to that certain component in the project directory. If you are in `<root>/components/video.vue` and the video file is `<root>/assets/videos/internal_path.mp4`, then the source would be `../assets/videos/internal_path.mp4`

Comment: When I preface the relative path with .. I get the error This dependency is not found